# Let $f: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $f$ is a local maximum at all $x\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

I first heard of the following problems when I was a freshman, and I remember that my TA showed me a very short and elegant solution which I am unable to recall now. I think I know how to solve it using (quite a lot of) $\epsilon-\delta$. I would like to see solutions which does not involve explicitly $\epsilon-\delta$.

Let $f: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $f$ is a local maximum at any $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Show that $f$ is constant.

If the continuity assumption is dropped, what can you say about $f$?

For the first problems, it is tempting for me to use reductio ad absurdum, visualize the graph of a non constant function to be some zig-zag curve and use local, i.e. $\epsilon-\delta$ arguments to show that this kind of functions will not satisfy the local maximality assumption. It would be nice if someone can come up with with a 'global' argument not involving $\varepsilon-\delta$ explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume there is a nonconstant continuous $f$ having a local maximum at all points $x\in{\mathbb R}$. Then there is such an $f$ with $f(0)=0$, $\>f(1)=1$.
Define
$$\tau:=\sup\bigl\{t\>\bigm|\>0\leq t\leq1, \ f(t)\leq0\bigr\}\ .$$
Continuity then implies $f(\tau)\leq0$ and $\tau<1$. Since $f(t)>0$ for $\tau<t\leq1$ the function $f$ cannot be locally maximal at $\tau$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The construction of $\tau$ is a clever one!

Answer (score 2):

For the first part, let $a\in\mathbb {R}.$ Then there is $\delta > 0$ such that $f(x)\le f(a)$ for all $x \in [a-\delta, a + \delta].$ Claim: $f$ is constant in this interval. Proof: Suppose $f(b) < f(a)$ for some $b\in (a,a+\delta].$ Let $m$ be the minimum value of $f$ on $[a,a+\delta];$ this minimum value exists by the continuity of $f.$ Then $m<f(a).$ Again using continuity, the set $\{x\in [a,a+\delta]: f(x) = m\}$ is compact, hence has a smallest element $c.$ Clearly $c>a.$ On the interval $[a,c)$ we have $f>f(c).$ That implies $f$ doesn't have a local maximum at $c,$ contradiction. Thus $f\equiv f(a)$ on $[a,a+\delta].$ The argument from the left is similar and the claim is proved.

The claim shows $f$ is locally constant. Now use a standard connectivity argument to show $f$ is constant on $\mathbb {R},$ say by showing the set where $f=f(0)$ is both open and closed.

If we drop the continuity hypothesis, then the function that is $1$ on the integers and zero everywhere else has a local maximum at each point of $\mathbb {R}.$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have just updated my question. You may also want to think of an alternative solution which does not involve $\varepsilon-\delta$.

Answer (score 0):

For the first problem: Let $c\in\text{Im}(f)$. The preimage $f^{-1}((-\infty, c])$ is open because of the local maximality assumption. By continuity this preimage is closed as well. Since it is non-empty, $f^{-1}((-\infty, c])$ must be $\mathbb{R}$, and thus $c$ is the global maximum.  Suppose there is another $c'\in\text{Im}(f)$ not equal to $c$. By the same argument $f^{-1}((-\infty, c'])=\mathbb{R}$, meaning that $c'$ is another global maximum, contradiction. So $\text{Im}(f)$ only consists of a single element and thus $f$ is constant.